# how to go Page row actions anchor page (post.php?post=3&action=? )

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a visual editor for that I want when anyone clicks edit with particle studio then it's open a blank page with his my own layout

[image]

I am done with `page_row_action` code below

```php
function ps_page_row_actions( $actions, $page_object ) {
    $admin_post_url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=', 'http' );
    $actions['particle_studio'] = '<a href="'.$admin_post_url.$page_object->ID . '&action=ps' . '">' . __('Edit with Particle Studio') . '</a>';
    return $actions;
}

add_filter('page_row_actions', 'ps_page_row_actions', 10, 2);
```

How can i go `post.php?post=3&action=pspage` with my own layout

Answer (score 2):

```
function handle_post_action_ps( $post_id ) {
    wp_die( 'Hello World '.$post_id );//wp_die is just for test
}

add_action( 'post_action_ps', 'handle_post_action_ps', 10, 1 );
```

The (post_action_ps) is the hook for your custom action "ps".

The function will handle the action.

---

You can set the name of the action to almost everything.

But in the URL must you must have same name for the action. Ex:

```
post.php?post=${post_id}&action=my-awesome-edit

add_action( 'post_action_my-awsome-edit', 'handle_my_awesome_edit', 10, 1 );
```

---

Ref links

post_action_{$action}: http://hookr.io/actions/post_action_action/

add_action: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

I hope this helps! :D

Comment: It doesn't work at all. Any complete example to do what was asked in the image?